# Exception android java.util.Objects in Android Version 4.3

Tags: java, android, exception, noclassdeffounderror

i'm getting issues with running my app in a device (android 4.3) and i'm getting this error :  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects

I know that The exception is thrown because all static methods of java.util.Objects are available above API 19 (Android 4.4.+) so that method doesn't exist in that Android version and NoClassDefFoundError is thrown.

But i also need my app to be compatible with version 4.3, how can i fix it ?

trace : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects at okhttp3.CertificatePinner.withCertificateChainCleaner(CertificatePinner.java:231) at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.(OkHttpClient.java:238) at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:1015)

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects
        at okhttp3.CertificatePinner.withCertificateChainCleaner(CertificatePinner.java:231)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:238)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:1015)

Comment: In case you want to add more information to the question please update the question instead of commenting it.

Comment: Done ! tnx im new

Answer (score 10):

You are probably using OkHttp 3.13.x or higher
3.13.0 is the first release of OkHttp that bumps minimum requirements to Android 5+ API 21

Please try the 3.12.3 version as it should support devices with Android 2.3+ (API 9+)

Source: https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/#version-3130

Answer (score 0):

Don't use those calls.  Provide your own version of them in your own class.  You can't use a function on a version of the OS before it was added.  There is no way to do it.  But you could find an open source implementation of those functions from something like OpenJDK and drop that class into your app and use it there.

But why are you spending effort to support 4.3?  Only .4% of all devices in use are v 4.3. Source-  Google:  https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/   It's not worth the effort and cost to support at this time.  All devices before 19 combines are only 3.5% of all devices in use, and those are heavily clustered geographically-  unless your main audience is in poor areas of Africa or Asia, you'll only see a fraction of that.  Likely you've already spent more money (as time) in looking into this issue than you'll ever get back in revenue.

Oh and note those numbers are from back in October-  it will be even  smaller now.

Comment: it's an intern project with old devices this is why i need this lowest version for android

Comment: the problem appears while using Okhttp

Comment: Just saw the stack trace you posted-  you're screwed.  Your networking library is requiring it.  Using an open source alternative likely won't work (if you were making Objects calls, it would).  You can try, but you'll probably need to use an old version of the networking library that doesn't have the issue.  Which for security reasons isn't recommended.